# How can add new enumeration in system enums?

Tags: c#, enums

How can I add new enumeration in system enums?

I want to add a new button-type (None=6) in `MessageBoxButton` enum:

Default list is:

```
MessageBoxButton.Ok=0
MessageBoxButton.Cancel=1
MessageBoxButton.AbortRetryIgnore=2
MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel=3
MessageBoxButton.YesNo=4
MessageBoxButton.RetryCancel=5
```

I want to add a new member:

```
MessageBoxButton.None=6
```

Comment: XY problem. Explain what problem you want to solve. What do you think this will do? If you could do this, WinForms isn't going to do anything (perhaps throw an exception) when it encounters a new value.

Comment: You cannot override `MessageBoxButton ` enum. You have to create one yourself and write your own logic to handle additional values.

Comment: simply creating myMessageBox in my apps (winforms) and want to popup a message till request is processing and this will be disappear on completed event. in that using a method which will get MessageboxButtons and i want to add a new None.

Comment: @FCin thx can u share sample please?

Comment: You have to create a new control and create `MessageBox`'s view that looks like the windows' one. There is no quick way to do it, because you have no way of overriding this control. You just have to create a new one that looks like the windows'.

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to show a modal dialog with no buttons whatsoever? That is bound to irritate its share of users.

Comment: The `MessageBoxButton` enum doesn't have those constants. It only has four. The enum that has the constants you mention is called `MessageBoxButtons`. They're totally different things.

Answer (score 1):

To actually have the enum changed you would need to file a change request, convince people (different people for the .NET Core and .NET Framework changes) that it's a good idea without significant backwards compatibility issues, and then wait until the change was made and use the new framework version.

This obviously isn't a practical short-term measure.

To have an extra value on an enum all you need to do is use it and look for it:

```
public static MessageBoxButton ReturnExtendedValue()
{
    return (MessageBoxButton)6;
}

public static bool IsMessageBoxButtonThePrivatelyUsedExtraValue(MessageBoxButton value)
{
    return value == (MessageBoxButton)6;
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        IsMessageBoxButtonThePrivatelyUsedExtraValue(
            ReturnExtendedValue())); // Prints "True"
}
```

Generally, `enum` does not limit values to those defined by the enum, it just gives some values meaning. You are free to apply your own meanings to values outside the defined range.

Generally also though, this isn't a great idea. For one thing, you don't know that the new value you've assigned won't be used in a future version of the framework. You are likely better off separating the states, with a `bool` return for whether there was a button press or not and an `out MessageBoxButton` indicating what it was if there was one.

If you are going to use values outside the defined range, using negative values is likely (but not guaranteed) to have fewer forwards compatibility issues.

Comment: many thx for sample. appreciated  let me check if work for me.

Comment: Although, as you've shown, you can create a `MessageBoxButtons` enum with a value of 6 (or -ve), what exactly is the use of that? This enum is passed to WinForms `MessageBox.Show` method to tell it how to display a message box. If you pass 6 to it, it will probably give you an exception. If you want to check for the enum value `None` in your own code, why use a system enum at all? Just write your own enum.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException the only value I could see is if most of the values used had a precise mapping to the existing values. I do though advise against the approach in my answer.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException i am creating MyMessageBox in winforms apps I want to popup a message which can be different types like wait, okay , Yes/No, cancel, ignore etc. these button will be showing based selected type. up to here is okay i can use default members but in my case i am showing waiting message without any button and this message will disappear automatically on completed request.its like in-progress animation. to do this want to pass a button type "none" in control within my method.